# Image from Arduino with camera ov7670 to Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi

i am stuck at sending picture to Raspberry pi from Arduino , how can i do this ? One way that i am using now is saving the picture on SD card module on the arduino , how to transfer that image to Raspberry pi? One problem is that the image on the SD card is in very "Raw format" which means , it needs to be converted to HEX and then we need to Add (bmp)headers or something i am not even sure, i have the python scripts that do this but the problem is it will slow down pi , and for my project its not acceptable that way. One other option is if i can stream the video that will be great . Some suggestions ? 
Thank yoin

EDIT
About the process of Opening with HEX edtior:

The image data that Arduino is going to write to the SD card is raw image data i.e. just plain byte data-one byte for one pixel. If you try to open it as an image file then it won’t work. It is not in proper format to be read as an image. That’s why you need to write a bmp file with proper headers and use the raw image data to fill in for the pixel data in the bmp file. Now, here is the part where I cheated a little bit. I just opened up the file containing raw image data that Arduino wrote and opened it in a hex editor.

LINK: https://hkalasua.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/ov7670-arduino-sd/

Comment: I edited my question , you can check

Comment: you are misunderstanding what HEX means ... it is a human readable representation of a number, specifically a binary number ... it is easier to read FE23 than 1111111000100011 ... the file you mentioned is binary ... there is no hex conversion involved

Comment: send the image data to the RPi and use a python script to generate the bmp or png file